# Checkboxes not appearing in listview choice mode multiple, fixes?

Tags: java, android

Might be because in the listview I'm adding objects and not strings. Anyone know how to get checkboxes to appear when using a listview of objects?

The main thing I'm tring to do right now is to have mutiple selections so I can delete the object in the listview.

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What have you done so far? show some code.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez unfortunately cant share code due to school reasons but do you know if the checkboxes appear in object listviews?

Comment: You can find other blogs or tutorials with more or less has the same implementation on what you are doing. And use that as a reference here. Or it will be difficult for us here to help you.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez scoured the internet and I have tried but all of them use strings instread of objects and the checkboxes appear for them

Comment: what would i need to show you for you to pick it apart?

Comment: Rename IDs or class names into something else, whatever. Your school shouldn't hold anything against it.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez added some images not sure if theyre helpful

Comment: Please use code blocks and not images. It seems like basic Android code, not sure why are you so concern of your school finding out.

Comment: hahah first time doing this so forgive me

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez added code block and more code

Comment: Looks fine, can you share EventsAdapter code?

Comment: I don't see no checkboxes here?

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez From the references I looked at it seemed that the checkboxes were a part of the mutiples selection mode. Still very new to android studio so this might be it

Comment: How would it look?